# Strange behaviour of additionalSafeAreaInsets

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm quite new to iOS development and I'm facing an unexpected and strange behaviour in UIViewController, when setting the additionalSafeAreaInsets variable.

The reason why Im setting the safe area constraint is that Im using this [library](https://github.com/kukushi/SideMenu) to implement a Side Menu on my App. As the library implements the Side Menu by using a UIViewController, that is the size of the full screen, offsets it completely to the left using the width of the screen and then reduces the offset by the predefined value to show the menu.  On portrait mode, I set a smaller additional left safe area value (e.g. 75, as the width is smaller) and in landscape I must use a larger value to describe the safe area (e.g. 364).

What happens is, that initially when in portrait everything works fine, then after rotating to landscape, everything works fine aswell. But when rotating from landscape to portrait, the larger landscape value is used and everything is offset to the right due to the incorrect value. The reason seems to be that I can only increase the additionalSafeAreaInsets variable values, but not decrease it?
Is this expected behaviour of UIKit and how to avoid it or reset the additionalSafeAreaInsets?

Below is some relevant code inside my UIViewController

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func updateLeftInset(size: CGSize) {

    let leftInset = size.width - SideMenuController.preferences.basic.menuWidth

    self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftInset, bottom: 0, right: 0)

}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    print("viewWillTransition")

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        updateLeftInset(size: size)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        updateLeftInset(size: view.bounds.size)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

Comment: A workaround for the issue for me was to use the plain old layout margin insets instead of safeAreaInsets. That actually worked better for me in the end, as it had backward compatibility with older iOS versions. Maybe this comment can give insight to someone struggling with this issue. Although, this does not answer the original question about additionalSafeAreaInsets, so I will leave the question open for now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is getting view's bounds in `viewDidLoad()` is wrong.

You should do it in `viewWillAppear`, you will get the correct value there.

As for why the value is wrong, the additionalSafeAreaInsets represents how much you want the view to decrease the safe area, so you probably want this:

`self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: SideMenuController.preferences.basic.menuWidth, bottom: 0, right: 0)`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a correct answer. If you had read my issue more closely, then you would have noticed that everything was alright after initial load. Problems raised, when I rotated from horizontal to portrait and when I tried to edit additionalSafeAreaInsets for smaller values.

As for this claim "As for why the value is wrong, the additionalSafeAreaInsets represents how much you want the view to decrease the safe area...". The variable name itself gives away that the variable increases the safe area insets.

Comment: @splangi Everything being alright after initial load is a coincidence, view.bounds.size is undefined in `viewDidLoad`.

The variable increases safe area _insets_, which decreases the safe area size [see here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area).